# Primefaces Push not work after deploy but work after restart glassfish 4.1

Tags: jsf, primefaces, glassfish, push, primefaces-push

I have a JSF project which uses primefaces push.
When I package war file and deploy it to glassfish 4.1, push desn't work,

```
<p:socket onMessage="handleMessage" channel="/myChannel" />
```

There is a chart page and when any other event occurs, below code runs.

```
EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();
eventBus.publish("/myChannel", map);
```

The expected is updating chart data with map's data.

Above code runs as expected if I restart server after deployment.
If I redeploy or (undeploy and deploy) project. Chart is not updated by eventBus anymore.

comet support and websocket support enabled on glassfish.

Any idea?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not something we can work with. You have to make that more specific

Comment: Thanks but really no words to say. There is no server log about problem or there is no error log on Chrome's developer tools. But I will try to update question with some details.

Comment: You can check IF there are sockets set up (or not) etc…

Comment: I do not understand why everything works if I restart server.

Comment: Me neither (not using glassfish) but that is what we want to figure out…  start eliminating things (checking in DETAIL what does and does not work.

Comment: E.g. check in the log if atmosphere is actually started etc

Comment: Thanks I will recheck logs and steps. Maybe previous socket connection must be closed on undeployment phase.